# getting values of table view headers

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm not able to access to the values of the headers of a table widget.

I'm able to set them like:

```
self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(words)
```

I've tried all the methods of header view object without any positive result.

Printing the header value with:

```
print(self.tableWidget.verticalHeader())
```

I obtain the object

```
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHeaderView object at 0x10ebc1798>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate using the `horizontalHeaderItem()`:

```
labels = []
for c in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
    it = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(c)
    labels.append(str(c+1) if it is None else it.text())
print(labels)
```

Comment: ok, now I've to find the way to add this as first line of an xls file and the adding the data for each row: my final purpose is exporting a table widget in an excel file including vertical and horizontal headers. can you help me? or do I need writing another post? tsk